# Manejo de archivo CSV en C++

Tags: c++

Estaba haciendo un programa que lee un archivo Csv , en su interior aparece una lista de nits, fecha y cantidad gastada y que una vez guardada esa información el programa tendría que calcular lo siguiente:

- Sumatoria NITs.
- La Media NITs.
- El NIT Mínimo.
- El NIT Máximo.

Mi programa ya suma los nits que estan repetidos en el archivo CSV, pero aun me falta sumar todas las cantidades gastadas , y sacar la media, el nit máximo , y mínimo, me ayude con un libro pero la verdad no logro hacer esa parte. Cualquier ayuda se los agradecería , Uso code block pero tengo habilitado la opción::: `Have g++ follow the c++11 Iso C++ language standard [-std=c++11]`

Así está mi programa, esto muestra actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi programa tiene que mostrar esta información:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo CSV tiene 1000 registros, más o menos está así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi programa. Cualquier ayuda, desde ya muchas gracias!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <map>

    void leer();

    class Dato{
          public:
          long nit;
          std::string fecha;
          double total;
          friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& obj);
           };

       std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& objeto)
       {
       os << "nit: " << objeto.nit << ", fecha: " << objeto.fecha << ", total: " << objeto.total;
        }

      int main()
      {
    leer();
    return 0;
   }

    void leer()
       {
     std::string nombre;
     std::ifstream infile("archivo.csv");
     std::string line;
     std::vector<Dato *> datos_csv;
     std::map<long, double> sumados;
      std::map<long, double>::iterator buscaSumados;
       while (getline(infile, line)) {
       std::stringstream strstr(line);
       std::string word;
        Dato *actual = new Dato();
        for (int indice = 0; getline(strstr, word, ','); indice++) {
        switch(indice) {
        case 0:
            actual->nit = std::stol(word);
            break;
        case 1:
            actual->fecha = word;
            break;
        case 2:
            actual->total = std::stod(word);
            break;
         }
       }

       datos_csv.push_back(actual);
       buscaSumados = sumados.find(actual->nit);

       if (buscaSumados == sumados.end()) {
        sumados.insert(std::pair<long, double>(actual->nit, actual->total));
       }
       else
         {
         buscaSumados->second += actual->total;
        }
       }

       system("color f0");
       std::cout<< "\n\n";
       std::cout<< "\t  TOTAL NIT" << "         " << "TOTAL GASTADO";
       std::cout<< "\n\n";

       for (std::map<long, double>::iterator i = sumados.begin(); i != sumados.end(); i++) {
        std::cout<< ""<< "\t NIT: " << i->first << ",  GASTADO: " << i->second << std::endl;
     }
    }
```

Comment: probaste de hacer un salto de linea?

Comment: Me resulta dificil creer que seas capaz de usar clases, archivos, mapas y cadenas de texto sin problemas y no sepas calcular un simple total. ¿Dónde está la trampa?

Comment: Y por cierto, las preguntas cerradas pueden reabrirse. No vas a obtener más respuestas saltándote las normas y duplicando la pregunta

Comment: Es que fijate que me estoy guiando en un libro que se llama : Curso de programacion  3era edicion de javier ceballos , pero aun me cuesta programar, estoy leyendo el libro pero aun no entiendo como hacer esa parte, igual me he puedo a investigar, de hecho el programa esta comentado pero aun no logro hacer esa parte.

Comment: Ese hombre ha sido profesor mio en la universidad. El caso es que me resulta curioso que hayas sido capaz de hacer lo más dificil (estructurar el código, sobrecargar operadores, usar streams, ...) y te lies con un sumando

Comment: @eferion te explico , he estado leyendo el libro de programación que se llama: Curso de programacion 3era de Javier Ceballos, en el hay he tomando la idea y he entendido el codigo, tambien he copiado linea de codigo porque no decirlo, obviamente me he puesto a invetigar , de hecho el programa esta comentado para entenderlo mejor, pero aun me cuenta programar este tipo de tema, por eso pregunte ayuda ,y discupa si por alguna razon salte alguna norma, solo buscaba ayuda.

Comment: No te saltas ninguna norma... pero las preguntas que haces demuestran que te falta la base... no vayas tan rápido e intenta asentar conocimientos. C++ es un lenguaje muy complicado y puñetero y si no vas con una base sólida va a dolerte la cabeza muy a menudo. Por otro lado, intento no responder preguntas que no son coherentes porque no pretendo hacerle los deberes a nadie, sino solo ayudar. Por eso he preguntado tanto en vez de responder... aunque ya tienes dos buenas respuestas. Eso si, hazte un favor y empieza el libro desde el principio... no avances demasiado mientras tengas dudas

Comment: @eferion de hecho eso he estado haciendo , todas las noches leo el libro que te comente, vos has tenido el honor de tener como profesor a el autor del libro y créeme que este libro me encanta, explica super bien.

Comment: @eferion Y decidí leerlo porque en la universidad no nos enseñaron buenas bases de programación en c++, el libro me ha enseñado que c++ es una mole de lenguaje de programación, y te das cuenta, mi base esta mala , y el problema esta que los profesores piensa que vos sabes y de una vez te tiran al agua y es hay donde te toca ver que hacer y dejas a un lado la buena practica de programación.

Gracias igual mi amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Para calcular el máximo y el mínimo se podría usar `std::max_element` y `std::min_element` respectivamente, ambos en el archivo de encabezado `algorithm`, y para el total y la media `std::accumulate` del encabezado `numeric`. Ya que los datos están dentro de un contenedor `std::map`, antes necesitas definir dos estructuras:

```
//para comparar
struct CompareSecond
{
    bool operator()(const std::pair<long,double>& left, const std::pair<long, double>& right) 
    {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};

//para acumular
struct AddValues
{
    double operator()(double value, const std::pair<long, double>& pair)
    {
        return value + pair.second;
    }
};
```

Luego podemos usar las funciones mencionadas para calcular lo que necesitas:

```
//para calcular el total
double sumanit = std::accumulate(sumados.begin(), sumados.end(), .0, AddValues());

//para el mínimo
std::pair<long,double> minpair = *std::min_element(sumados.begin(), sumados.end(),CompareSecond());
double mini = minpair.second;

//para el máximo
std::pair<long, double> maxpair = *std::max_element(sumados.begin(), sumados.end(), CompareSecond());
double maxi = maxpair.second;

//el promedio ya es trivial
double prom = sumanit / sumados.size();
```

**Mas información:**

1. [How can I find the minimum value in a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659275/8601080)
2. [Adding all values of map using std::accumulate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356024/8601080)

Comment: muchisimas gracias Bro. Me ayudaste muchísimo, me sacaste de la duda y gracias a vos pude sacar esos datos, de verdad muchas gracias..!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Si ya estás definiendo el operador de escritura de información para `Dato`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Dato& objeto)
{
    return os << "nit: " << objeto.nit << ", fecha: " << objeto.fecha << ", total: " << objeto.total;
//  ^^^^^^ <---- Te faltaba el retorno.
}
```

No veo por qué no puedes definir el operador de lectura de información para `Dato`:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Dato& objeto)
{
    is >> objeto.nit;
    is.ignore(1);

    char fecha[9]{};
    is.read(fecha, 8);
    objeto.fecha = fecha;
    is.ignore(1);

    is >> objeto.total;

    return is;
}
```

De esta manera, puedes leer directamente del archivo y rellenar en un `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Dato> datos;

if (std::ifstream infile{archivo})
{
    Dato dato;
    while (infile>> dato)
    {
        datos.push_back(dato);
    }
}
```

Date cuenta que no es necesario que el vector almacene punteros, así puedes ahorrarte toda la gestión de memoria haciendo que tu programa sea más sencillo y fácil de mantener. Una vez leídos todos los datos, sacar el mínimo, máximo y promedio es trivial usando utilidades de `<numeric>` y `<algorithm>`:

```
// Para vínculos estructurados necesitarás C++17 o superior.
auto [minimo, maximo] = std::minmax_element(datos.begin(), datos.end(),
// Para lambdas genéricas necesitarás C++14 o superior.
[](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a.nit < b.nit; });

auto suma = std::accumulate(datos.begin(), datos.end(), .0,
// Para lambdas genéricas necesitarás C++14 o superior.
[](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return a + b.nit; });

std::cout << "Minimo: " << minimo->nit << '\n'
    << "Maximo: " << maximo->nit << '\n'
    << "Suma: " << suma << '\n'
    << "Promedio: " << suma / datos.size();
```

Puedes ver el programa funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRNb9swDD3bv0LIgNZBZc/5TprUp10HDNgxDQpFURxtthTIdlesyF9vRlFyF7fDgI0gEpOPJh8p0fx4jHPOz@cPUvGi2QmykrqqjWBlFv72gUeqvON5H/QoeK3NpUc1pTCSX7pYkWsj6wO8GUKKhtfkE6s1eQ6DQqucKFkvw6Cqd7e3rijZC35g4NvpZlsIUuuaFWDujRRqRzDSM74i@igMZDOrVfQGqCjhWlWuGtjbb/1leFpaEv@bQNS6HwJvI@rGKIggqxXpQQO3pGcfXUgCDgSo66QLosvD2FkX9s2ePE35lmaWRV1AAs13BGVFsuyCztK6EpkrbUQ0gDmEAbAwjt96sXk@uQhIuYvQSckcwoIO6bvXk3mbrFPPt/A6JllhP1LVpGRSRcgQJyuejoYgEWb4QT7q9SYMAAx6g1ZoOohRKRjJYHCvehYftkLTYYxKwUiGQ4@PWqHpKEalYCSjkcfHrdB0HKNSMJLx2OOTVmg6iVEpGMlk4vFpKzSdxqgUjGQ69fisFZrOYlQKRjKbeXzeCk3nsdUBBSOZzz2@aIWmixiVgpEsFhYPA3uN3cq4FVzZG5CRHfxWr5DbJndPiFR7WYjIz9keLS6hfQOefxwAJJELskdp/X13Fpg0OTbV4WHL@PcIIXgHjjRgDeRYl1LJUlM43Sf438A9wfrgBs@DKEQpVB25PFuR2ytAHdcEFhqMMFhvIrdrmPGKtavnzG2fPBN/m5hbL7LFe01OlgpGVU3J2tKM86ZsClaLv5UlSfpvpcnNZVk/Zq4bt@6fcQx@nd1M4sx/C67v1TXMEsNwSm0YGn8K@wrt@CDsrIt@MboUO6kvIz765ir5U0T9iwVMYf/O5xe@L1henWNgfcdvbobsFw)</kbd>.

Comment: Compila con C++11 ... esto no va a funcionar

Comment: Pues que active C++17. C++11 es de hace nueve años.

Comment: ya bueno, quizá si dice que usa esas opciones, pueden ser una exigencia... no lo sabemos y se supone que la utilidad del portal es dar las respuestas que la gente necesita, no las que nosotros querríamos dar

Comment: "*Uso code block **pero** tengo habilitado C++11*" no me parece una frase que denote limitación si no resignación. No se trata de que yo quiera dar estas respuestas, es que me niego a dar respuestas que fomenten malas prácticas como usar código de hace casi una década.

Comment: No creo que ni tan siquiera el 10% ded código C++ existente haya adoptado aún C++14 ... no hablemos ya de C++17

Comment: @eferion que tal Bro, es que el problema esta en que a nosotros como alumnos nos meten de lleno a programar, y nos explica ese tipo de conceptos , desde hay comenzamos a llevar una mala practica de programación, que para nosotros esta bien porque no nos dicen nada los maestros.

Comment: Claro que ni el 10% del código existente está más allá de C++14, es normal, ya que más del 90% del código existente es *legacy*. Para desarrollos nuevos debería usarse código moderno, no código antiguo.